# How can I specify a proxy for Mailjet with the Php wrapper?

Tags: php, mailjet

On my new server, I have to use a proxy to make the different API calls to other services.

I'm using Mailjet, and making the calls with the official PHP Wrapper (with no composer : https://github.com/mailjet/mailjet-apiv3-php-no-composer ).

I try to configure the proxy like that :

```
$mj = new \Mailjet\Client(
                APIKEY,
                APIKEY2,
                true,
                [
                    'version' => 'v3.1',
                    'connect_timeout' => 4,
                    'proxy' => [
                        'http' => someurl,
                        'https' => someurl
                    ]
                ]
            );
```

As you can see I'm also trying to edit the "CONNECT_TIMEOUT" variable. (I tried to set the variables in uppercase too, same result)

Unfortunaly, through all my tests I could have observe that only `version` and `url` variables are considered and set as asked. Any other variable, random or supposed to be taken care of, are not setted and stay with their default value.

I guess I'm not configuring as I should, perhaps those options should be elsewhere in the call, but even the Mailjet Support couldn't have inform me...

In the mean time I edited the `/Mailjet/src/Mailjet/Client.php` file from

```
 private $requestOptions = [
    self::TIMEOUT => 15,
    self::CONNECT_TIMEOUT => 2,
];
```

to

```
 private $requestOptions = [
    self::TIMEOUT => 15,
    self::CONNECT_TIMEOUT => 4,
    self::PROXY => someurl
];
```

It works, but I prefer not having to edit this file and pass the variables as I should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That class has a public method called [setConnectionTimeout](https://github.com/mailjet/mailjet-apiv3-php-no-composer/blob/f19e200c0971868e562c60bc392501896e325d8d/src/Mailjet/Client.php#L207) which you can use in your Client instance (e.g `$mj->setConnectionTimeout(4)`)

Comment: I know it's a shame but I'm not very competent with the class's ways...
So should I do something like `$mj->setConnectionTimeout(4)` right after the `$mj = new Mailjet\Client\()` ? Ok you edited your comment haha, thank you, i'll try it asap :)

Comment: Exactly, after instantiation or before you actually use it (`$mj->post...` or whatever).

Comment: Simple as that, it did the trick. The worst part is I saw those methods but I thought I just had to add those options in the call itself. Thanks, problem solved